# Geometry node's 'pointiness' channel not finding for edges

Tags: materials, node-editor, shaders, shader-nodes

I've been trying for several projects now to get a good procedural weathering effect using the geometry node's 'pointiness' value in the materials. I feel like I understand how the setup is meant to work, but I always get a weird scattering across the entire object, seemingly irrespective of edge location. It's more like a cow pelt pattern than anything else. I've fiddled with the color ramp sliders until *the cows come home*, but I've not had any luck getting this effect to stick to the edges. What very simple woopsie an I making?

[image]

Comment: your colorramp handles should surround .5 because that's where pointiness changes.